# delete a charac and replace another in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to do two thing :

- Delete "S" if the String ends with and if a consonant is before .
- Replace all "S" in the String if the character is between two vowels.

here is my code now :

```
public class Phonias{

    static String[] consonnant={"B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","P","Q","R","S","T","V","W","X","Z"};
    static String [] vowels={"A","E","I","O","U","Y"};

    public static String phonias1(final String str){

        if (str == null){
            return "null";
        }
        if(str==""){
            return "";
        }
        if (str.contains("S")){

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < consonnant.length; i++) {
            if(str.endsWith(consonnant[i]+"S") && str.length()>3){
                String temp = str.replaceAll(consonnant[i]+"S",consonnant[i]+"");
                return temp;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
            if( str.contains(vowels[i]+"S"+vowels[i])){

                return str.replace("S"+vowels[i], "Z"+vowels[i]);

            }
        }
        return str;

    }
}
```

All my test runs well except the "ISISIDORETS" it return me "ISISIDORET".

Comment: I appreciate that you're not a native English speaker - however `tampon` has a rather different meaning in English than it does in French. Just something to bear in mind when you're posting on an English language site!

Comment: Side note: **never** compare strings using ==. You can change your check for empty string to `tampon.isEmpty()`. In order to debug your actual problem - try running it in debugger; or print your "return values to System.out.

Comment: "ISISIDORETS" is matched in your first loop.

Comment: Don't use [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). It is for regular expressions. Use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Comment: @JonK - for the curiosity, it has actually both meanings in French, or at least close enough. It can mean tampon or buffer (and also stamp) (ok, it's weird, I'll give you that).

Comment: @Gnoupi I had assumed it was intended to be "buffer" in this context - I wasn't aware that it had alternative meanings as well. Although it does make a strange kind of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning `temp` in the first loop, thus the second loop is never executed. Simply update `tampon` and return it in the end. Like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < consonnant.length; i++) {
    if(tampon.endsWith(consonnant[i]+"S") && tampon.length()>3){
        tampon = tampon.replaceAll(consonnant[i]+"S",consonnant[i]+"");//supprime le "S" final s'il est situé après une consonne
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
    if( tampon.contains(vowels[i]+"S"+vowels[i])){
        tampon = tampon.replace("S"+vowels[i], "Z"+vowels[i]);//si le "S" précède une voyelle, remplacer par "Z" 
    }
}
return tampon;
```